# I need a bbl file with specific format?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using a latex template for my thesis. The template has a bbl file with following format:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Knuth(1984)}]{texbook}
{\sc Knuth, D.E.} (1984). {\em The {{\TeX}book}\/}. Addison-Wesley.

\bibitem[{Lamport(1986)}]{latex}
{\sc Mohsen, L.} (1986). {\em {\LaTeX:} {A} Document Preparation System\/}.
Addison-Wesley.

\bibitem[{Rudin(1973)}]{Rud73}
{\sc Rudin, W.} (1973). {\em Functional {Analysis}\/}. McGraw-Hill, New York.

\bibitem[{Taylor R.L(1991)}]{Zienkiewicz}
Zienkiewicz, O.C, Taylor R.L(1991) The Finite Element Method, Vol 2: Solid and Fluid Mechanics, Dynamics and Non-Linearity. McGraw-Hill 

\end{thebibliography}
```

I am going the take my reference list from Mendeley but I face two issues:

1.Mendeley creates a bib file not a bbl file

2.I need to have the format shown above but it gives me something like this:

```
@article{,
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/mohsen/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Unknown - 1991 - Rheologica Acta Calculation of residual stresses in injection molded products.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {\_flow-,\_numerical analysis,\_thermally-induced residual stresses,amorphous,c\_ompressible l\_eonov model,induced residual s\_tresses,injection \_molding,notation and symbols,polymers,viscoelasticity},
pages = {284--299},
title = {{Rheologica Acta Calculation of residual stresses in injection molded products}},
volume = {299},
year = {1991}
}
```

I was wondering if anybody could help me how to resolve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your four `\bibitem` examples perfectly illustrate one of the main perils of do-it-yourself construction of bibliographic entries: *inconsistent formatting*. The first three have the name of the author(s) -- last names and initials of first names -- in small-caps, the book title in italics, and a space betwee the author name(s) and the publication. In contrast, the fourth entry applies does not ahere to any of these rules. You will find that making a small effort into learning the basics of .bib files and selecting a suitable bibliography style file will pay off handsomely.

Comment: By the way, the Mendeley-generated entry of type `@article` you've posted is missing two required fields: `author` and `journal`. Absent these pieces of information, don't expect much good to come from running BibTeX or biblatex on this entry.

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom-formats like this is a type of problem that the recent [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) project is well adapted to. When replacing BibTeX with Bibulous, the OP's desired reference list format can be created with the following style template file:

```
TEMPLATES:
book = \textsc{<au>} (<year>). \textit{<title>}. <publisher>[, <address>].
OPTIONS:
namelist_format = last_name_first
```

(Note that the above shows the *entire* file, and that I only defined templates for `book` entries, since the OP only lists books.) This template shows the author list `<au>`, year `<year>`, book title `<title>`, and publisher `<publisher>` fields as *required* fields, and the `<address>` field as optional.